# Str replace and logical

Tags: php, str-replace

I want to replace `{` by `{{}` and `}` by `{}}`, because, I need to escape those `{` & `}` with `{}`.
if I've as input `{blah}` I want my script to output `{{}blah{}}`, see?
But it is not working look at what I did

```
$output = str_replace(array("}", "{"), array("{}}", "{{}"), '{blah}');
```

But as output I got this : `{{}blah{{}}}` instead of `{{}blah{}}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP iterates the whole string for each array item you put in the $search parameter.

It is in fact replacing `'{blah}'` into `'{blah{}}'` with your first array item `'{'`, and then from that into `'{{}blah{{}}}'` because there is another `'{'` after the first replacement.

You better off doing this with regular expression, with a single RegExp pattern it will run only once in your input string.

```
$str = preg_replace('/(\{|\})/', '{\\1}', '{blah}');
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because the replacement itself contains the string to search for. I would rewrite it with `preg_replace_callback` instead:

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/{|}/', function($match) {
    return $match[0] == '{' ? '{{}' : '{}}';
}, '{bla}');

// {{}bla{}}
```